# Write line from text file if regex finds specific word

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have multiple regex conditions in my application when my program reads and finds certain wording. I have a new requirement to write out that line to the `Message.Body` in my IF statement. I only need to look back 15 minutes. How do I send the line with this wording?

This is what the log file starts with before an error happens:
    `10/30/2014 7:19:06 AM 19993108 There is not enough space on the disk:` I need the number after the time and before the message more than anything.

```
//This section looks for matching the words

Regex regex2 = new Regex("(?<time>.+(AM|PM)).*There is not enough space on the disk.");
var lastFailTime2 = File.ReadLines(file)
.Select(line => regex2.Match(line))
.Where(m => m.Success) // take only matched lines
.Select(m => DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["time"].Value))
.DefaultIfEmpty() // DateTime.Min if no failures
.Max();
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the fastest way would be using the [Linq Extensions Library](https://linqlib.codeplex.com/).

It's got an [ElementAtMax()](http://linqlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MinMaxAvg) extension method, which returns the element for which the maximum selected value occurs (as opposed to LINQ `Max()`, which returns said maximum value).

EDIT: If for some reasons you need to avoid adding third party libraries to your code, it's not that complicated to write one yourself (though if at all possible, go with the former - this is basically reinventing the wheel):

```
public static TSource ElementAtMax<TSource, TComparable>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TComparable> selector) where TComparable : IComparable
{
    /* check for empty/null arguments */

    TSource result = default(TSource);
    TComparable currentMax = null;
    bool firstItem = true;

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
       if (firstItem)
       {
          result = item;
          currentMax = selector(item);
          firstItem = false;
          continue;
       }

       var nextVal = selector(item);
       if (currentMax != null && currentMax.CompareTo(nextVal) > 0)
          continue;

       currentMax = nextVal;
       result = item;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am a little confused. How is this tied into my current regex method? Being in a government outfit, I would need to jump through hoops to use anything 3rd party. What is the difficulty in getting the line of the text file where the wording is located?

Comment: Replace `.Select(m => DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["time"].Value)).DefaultIfEmpty().Max()` with `.ElementAtMax(m => DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["time"].Value))`

Answer (score 0):

I would get a string of the file's text, and then use the `IndexOf` method to find the index of the match string (`m.ToString()`) within the text of the file. Then just count the number of instances of the newline character from the beginning of the text to the index of the match. Use this count to determine what line it occurred on.

Comment: I need to get the whole line where the regex is a match. Not having luck getting the value with the date/time, the filing number and the matching regex